# Save ip on a online mysql database on window startup

Tags: database, windows, save, ip

I'm trying to redirect from my domain to my localhost, the issue is that I have dinamic Ip address so it changes periodically.
Is there any app that saves my ip into my online mysql database? (so then I can set the redirect using php)

If you know any other solution it will be welcome! :)

Thanks!

PD: I've tried no-ip but I don't want to pay for use my own domain.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows you can set an scheduled task to run on startup, but would be better to make run periodicaly because your ip address can change even without a restart.

Make The scheduled task run a script, can be php or ruby or phyton, they all have mysql adapters and can be run without a webserver, and in a bat script you can pass the ip address as an argument and The script send it to mysql.

If was Linux you could do a bash script.

Even dinamic ips can use dns servers, you should look into it too.